# Return the index of a column with highest total sale?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, indexing

I have a totalSale array that gets me the sum total of sales for each product. For example index 0 in the array gives me the total sales of product1, so on. My next methods output should simply return the index of the product with the highest total sales. This is my code but it is not outputting the correct answer and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me?

```
   public static int mostpopularProduct( int[] totalSale)
{
    int mostPopularProduct=0;
    int firstProduct=totalSale[0];

    for(int i=1;i<totalSale.length;i++)
    {
     if(totalSale[i]>firstProduct)
     {

         mostPopularProduct=i;
        }


    }

    System.out.println("Most popular product :" + popularProduct);
    return popularProduct;
}
```

Comment: You are setting `mostPopularProduct` and printing `popularProduct`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `mostPopularProduct` and printing `popularProduct` Also `if(totalSale[i]>firstProduct)` condition will always compare with the first product and not actually most popular product

Try this code

```
public static int mostpopularProduct( int[] totalSale) {
    int mostPopularProduct=0;


        for(int i=1;i<totalSale.length;i++) {
             if(totalSale[i]>totalSale[mostPopularProduct]) {
                 mostPopularProduct=i;
             }
        }


    System.out.println("Most popular product :" + mostPopularProduct);
    return mostPopularProduct;
 }
```

P.S. You might want to look for what to return if totalSale length is 0 as in that case there are no products so `mostPopularProduct` cannot be determined. Right now, this program will just return 0 in that case

Comment: why do you have the confusing `if(totalSale.length > 1 ) {`?  Surely the `for` would be enough?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes for would be enough. Just wanted to ensure it runs if there are more than 1 elements. Else `totalSale[i]>totalSale[mostPopularProduct]` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: That code would not be entered into if `totalSale.length` is not greater than 1

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue and makes sense!

Comment: @ScaryWombat exactly my point. If its not greater than 1 and there is just 1 element in that array. Then `mostPopularProduct` will be 0 which is already set as 0. If there are no elements in the array, then `mostPopularProduct` cannot be determined and in that case also `mostPopularProduct` is currently returning as 0 which is wrong and that's why I mentioned this in the PS section of my answer. Hope this clarifies

Comment: No, consider your code `for(int i=1;i<totalSale.length;i++) {` - if `totalSale.length` is less or equal to `1` the `for` loop will not be entered into, so the preceding `if(totalSale.length > 1 )` is **not** needed

Comment: @ScaryWombat my bad. Corrected it now

Answer (score -2):

// You need to set the max value product. Otherwise you are always comparing with the first one only.
 firstProduct = totalSale[i];

Comment: The reason for down voting please ?